# TCP push-pull socket server design

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I am designing a cross-platform messaging service as a learning exercise.  I have programmed socket-based servers before, but always a "client-polls-server" design, like a web server.  I want to be able to target mobile platforms, and I read that polling is a battery drain, so I would like to do push notification.

The server will be TCP-based, written in C++.  What I'm having trouble getting my head around is how to manage the bi-directional nature of the design.  I need a client to be able to send packets to the server as normal, but also listen for packets.  How do I mitigate situations like,  the client is sending data when the server is trying to send to it, or it's blocked listening for data but then needs to send something?

For example, consider the following crude diagram:

[image: crude diagram]

So, let's say client A is in the middle of sending a chunk of data (arrow 1).  While this is happening, client B sends a message (arrow 2), which causes the server to attempt to send data back to client A (arrow 3), but client A hasn't finished sending arrow 1 yet.  What happens in this instance?  Should I setup 2 separate ports on each client, one for inbound, one for outbound?  Do I need to keep track of the state of each connection?

Or is there a better approach to this altogether?

Comment: a tcp connection is bi-directional. once you've got a connection a<->server and server<->b, either side of both connections can send a packet to the other end. the more important decision is how to structure/format your data so you can identify what each packet means.

Comment: Don't use the term "packets" (a network layer thing) to refer to application-layer messages. It will only cause confusion.

Comment: @MarcB I know you can both send and receive data on a TCP connection, but can you do both simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, you can do both simultaneously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One socket port is inherently bidirectional. To handle both inbound and outbound traffic more or less concurrently you need to use nonblocking sockets.

Comment: @Alnitak You don't mean "or", you mean "and". Using select on blocking sockets leads to all kinds of problems. (A select hit doesn't guarantee a future operation won't block. How could it?)

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks, fixed it. If you delete your comment, I'll delete this one.

Comment: So as long as I don't block, for example in a blocking receive, they can read/write data simultaneously, and I'm overthinking this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is pretty simple. The TCP server should have a list with connected clients. Since a TCP connection is bi-directional, the push mechanism is quite simple.

Another important thing, as long as your server isn't multithreaded, you can read from or write to one client at the same time.